# SharePoint 2010 - Loop through all document libraries, create a view and set it as default

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I'm having trouble debugging this script. It is based on an earlier question on SO and it is very nearly working.

Requirement:
The script loops through each document library on a web application, creates a view called "Detailed" and sets it as the default view.

Issue:
It seems to be failing to loop through site collections. It will create the view successfully on the first site collection and it's libraries but fails on subsequent site collections.

Hopefully it's just something simple. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Ashley

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue

$siteURL = "http://dev1share"
$site = Get-SPSite($siteURL)

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {

$listCounter = $web.Lists.Count
for($i=0;$i -le $listCounter;$i++) {

    $list = $web.Lists[$i]
    if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") {
    $newList = $web.Lists.item($list.ID);


  $viewfields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection 
  $viewfields.Add("DocIcon") 
  $viewfields.Add("LinkFilename") 
  $viewfields.Add("_UIVersionString") 
  $viewfields.Add("Modified") 
  $viewfields.Add("Created") 
  $viewfields.Add("Editor") 
  $viewfields.Add("FileSizeDisplay") 

  [void]$newList.Views.Add("Detailed", $viewfields, "", 100, $true, $true)
  $newList.Update();

  $view=$newList.Views["Detailed"]
  $view.DefaultView = $true
  $view.Update()
}
}

$web.Dispose();
}
$site.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script loops only in 1 site collection called `[http://dev1share][1]`

If you want to loop all site collections you must get the webapplication object, not SP-Site which is lower in Sharepoint hierarchy model.

To get webapplication object and iterate - use code like this:

```
$webapplication = Get-SPWebApplication "Webapplication Name"
foreach($site in $webapp.Sites){
    foreach($web in $site.AllWebs){
        // Your script with creating views
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Redzio, thanks. Feeling silly. Will test it with the change.

Comment: That was indeed all it was. It still throws an error while running through but it doesn't seem to prevent the scrip from running and works as expected. Thanks.